# Jboss no message recived for Consumer

Tags: java, jboss, jms-topic

Hello I would like to ask
for help regarding Jboss,

I've got some message in jboss server

> 13:07:25,452 WARN [SimpleConnectionManager] A problem has been
>   detected with the connection to remote client
>   5c4o1h-e1pcdx-iqypqcxv-1-iqypqebx-d,
>   jmsClientID=b-3pdqpyqi-1-vxcqpyqi-xdcp1e-h1o4c5. It is possible the
>   client has exited without closing its connection(s) or the network has
>   failed. All associated connection resources will be cleaned up.

and when i run producer then consumer, the consumer do not recieve any message

Im a newbie in Jboss so please do forgive me for this question.

Comment: show us some code. How do you open an jms connection?

Comment: oh i already solved the problem. I found out that Standard Bindings is causing the failure which  i found here in this link https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6506